# powershell gui form for ping a computer

Tags: powershell

i just made a powershell gui form for pinging computers in my network.
The problem is, that the "ok" button is not working reliable.
Sometimes it is working, sometimes it is not.
What is always working is hitting enter button after entering the computername in the gui.
what is the problem with the script?
my code is the following. maybe you guys have an idea?

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

# form specs
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "Check Network Status"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,170)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.MaximumSize = $objForm.Size
$objForm.MinimumSize = $objForm.Size

# form icon  
$objForm.BackgroundImage = $objImage
$objForm.BackgroundImageLayout = "None"
# None, Tile, Center, Stretch, Zoom

$objForm.Width = $objImage.Width
$objForm.Height = $objImage.Height 

# label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(7,10)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,15)
$objLabel.BackColor = "Transparent"
$objLabel.ForeColor = "yellow"
$objLabel.Text = "Enter Computer Name"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

# input box
$objTextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,45)
$objTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextbox)

# ok button
$objButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$objButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,44)
$objButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$objButton.Text = "OK"
$objButton.Add_Click($button_click)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objButton)

# return status
$returnStatus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$returnStatus.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,70)
$returnStatus.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
$returnStatus.BackColor = "Transparent"
$returnStatus.Text = ""
$objForm.Controls.Add($returnStatus)

# action item here 
$button_click =
{  
$returnStatus.Text = ""  
$objStatusBar.Text = "Checking status..."
$computerName = $objTextbox.Text

# output - online  
if (Test-Connection $computerName -quiet -Count 2){
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$computerName is online"
$returnStatus.BackColor = "Transparent"
$returnStatus.ForeColor = "lime"
$returnStatus.Text = "Status: Online"
}
Else{
# output - offline
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$computerName is offline"
$returnStatus.ForeColor= "Red"
$returnStatus.Text = "Status: Offline"
}   
$objStatusBar.Text = "Done" 
}  

# form status bar  
$objStatusBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.StatusBar
$objStatusBar.Name = "statusBar"
$objStatusBar.Text = "Ready"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objStatusBar)

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){& $button_click}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
{$objForm.Close()}})

# modal
$objForm.Topmost = $True
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $button_click before assigning it to the button :

```
# action item here 
$button_click =
{  
$returnStatus.Text = ""  
$objStatusBar.Text = "Checking status..."
$computerName = $objTextbox.Text

# output - online  
if (Test-Connection $computerName -quiet -Count 2){
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$computerName is online"
$returnStatus.BackColor = "Transparent"
$returnStatus.ForeColor = "lime"
$returnStatus.Text = "Status: Online"
}
Else{
# output - offline
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$computerName is offline"
$returnStatus.ForeColor= "Red"
$returnStatus.Text = "Status: Offline"
}   
$objStatusBar.Text = "Done" 
}  
# ok button
$objButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$objButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,44)
$objButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$objButton.Text = "OK"
$objButton.Add_Click($button_click)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objButton)
```